# Why does this code use so much memory?

Tags: 8, nodes

I've got code that loops through nodes in order to generate processed output.

I've previously done an entity query that provided an array of node IDs. My main loop code looks like this.

```php
foreach ($this->nids as $nid) {
  $node = Node::load($nid);
  $nodeData = $node->toArray();
  $nodeURL = $node->toUrl()->toString();
  print "Mem usage: " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n<br>";
}
```

Obviously, the loop shown here is a minimal example to demonstrate the problem; as it stands, it's pretty useless as it doesn't do anything with the data it loads.

However, the loop is eating memory. The debug call to `memory_get_usage(true)` in the loop gives a bigger number every time, until the script eventually runs out of memory if I feed it enough nodes (about 300 seems to be enough to kill it).

Obviously, I can increase the memory available, but I'm reluctant to do that because I can't see why the loop would be use so much memory in the first place.

Can anyone please explain why this fairly basic loop is using much memory, and what I can do to prevent it?

A few additional notes:

- I've tried adding `unset()` at the end of the loop to clear the node and data variables; this doesn't have any effect (I wasn't expecting it to, but I tried it anyway).
- The nodes in question have about fifty custom fields, including a couple that are paragraphs, which in turn have fields of their own.
- My real code passes the node data to a processor class that re-formats it for use elsewhere. It builds an array of these objects, but they aren't causing the issue.

I'm currently running on Drupal 8.6.

Comment: It’’s not a leak as such - nodes are statically cached when they’re loaded. Load enough of them and the static cache will fill up the available memory. You can use [`EntityStorageBase::resetCache`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AresetCache/8.2.x) to alleviate the problem

Comment: Well, sure, you are doing a foreach over a large list that is calling `node_load`, which in itself makes other calls. Thats a ton of operations.

Comment: Firstly, just replace Node::load($nid) with Node::loadMultiple($this->nids) and using for foreach.

Comment: You find an example for @Clive's comment in this question posted recently https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280633/performance-issue-while-loop-through-all-groups-and-create-node-for-each

Comment: Thanks @Clive. See my self-answer; I was able to use your tip to help resolve this. Other comments here helped me get a bit further, but thank you for giving the first useful tip.

Comment: @Jonh: Thanks for your advice. `loadMultiple()` does indeed perform a whole lot better (although I did need to limit it to 100 records at a time). I guess this is a symptom of drupal's underlying DB design: Loading a traditional DB table would be tolerably quick even doing it one-at-a-time, but because Drupal puts each field into its own table, a single entity load can be dozens of DB hits. It looks like `loadMultiple()` cuts down a lot on the DB hits which is why it's so much quicker.

Comment: @4k4: Thanks for the link; the example you linked to was helpful, although I did need to do further digging to get it right. I've posted my solution below, so hopefully it'll be helpful for anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: This is what the Batch API is for.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/group/batch/8.6.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With thanks to the comments made by various people above, I have now optimised this code so that it doesn't run out of memory.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($this->nids, 100);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($chunk);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        //do stuff with the node here...
    }
    Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache([$chunk]);
    print "Mem usage: ".memory_get_usage(true)."\n<br>";
}
```

I couldn't simply do `loadMultiple` for all the nodes at once as it was still using unholy amounts of memory, but chunking it and resetting the cache after each chunk seems to work nicely.

I experimented with different sized chunks, and I found I got the best mix of performance vs memory usage with the chunk size at 100. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Fool proof method: `$memory_cache->deleteAll()`.

```php
$memory_cache = \Drupal::service('entity.memory_cache');
$entity_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'issues')
  ->execute();
    
$chunks = array_chunk($nids, 100);
    
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
  $entities = $entity_storage->loadMultiple($chunk);
    
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    // Do your stuff with the node/other entities.
  }
    
  $memory_cache->deleteAll();
}
```

`$memory_cache->deleteAll()` will delete the cached items from memory. I had a script that would load entity reference entities and that would not free the used memory, even after doing all the possible cache resets like suggested in the other answer. The only thing that worked for me is deleting everything.

Comment: Note that with long running scripts this helps reduce memory usage but there is still a leak happening somewhere and memory usage keeps growing albeit at a slower rate.