# PHP Script taking up way more memory than expected

Tags: 8

We have a script that is meant to clean up some user data. Essentially, we 1) load all user ids and loop through them. For each user we 1) load the user object then 2) alter some data and finally 3) we save the user.

We originally did all of this in one script file but we were running into memory issues about 15% of the way through processing all the users and weren't certain why. So we've tried the following:

1. Unset any variable instanced in the for-loop at the end of the for-loop using `unset`
2. Any variable instanced in the for-loop is set to `NULL` at the end of the for-loop
3. Loading, Altering, and Saving the user object functionality was extracted to a service method that the script will call

The hope for attempted fixes 1 and 2 would be that the memory would be deallocated and php's garbage collector would clear up memory, but it did not

The hope for attempted fix 3 was that the memory from the user object and all that would be cleaned up after the service function finished since, I believe, it should run on a different process.

I'm very confused as I don't know what variable(s) are taking up so much memory, if anything, the list of user ids should be the largest variable taking up memory but it doesn't even take up that much... In our D7 project, I had many scripts that ran through each user and did some work and saved the user and it had no issues, but in this D8 version I'm having memory issues.

Here is the code we have now, and I simply cannot find anything here that would suggest something continually to take up memory...

**Script**

```
<?php
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$user_service = \Drupal::service('my_user.my_user_service');

$uids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
                ->condition('status', '1')
                ->execute();
$total_users = count($uids);
$user_index = 0;

foreach($uids as $uid) {
  $user_index += 1; 
  
  $ytp_user_service->cleanUp($uid);

  $percent_complete = ($user_index / $total_users) * 100;
  $percent_complete_formatted = number_format($percent_complete, 2, '.', ' ');
  $memory =  memory_get_usage()/1000000;
  print_r("\r\033[KUSER: {$uid} | COMPLETION: {$percent_complete_formatted}% | MEMORY:  {$memory} MB");
  $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
}
```

**Service Method**

```
  function cleanUp($uid) {
    $today = new DateTime();
    $entityManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
    $fields = $entityManager->getFieldStorageDefinitions('user', 'user');
    $countries = options_allowed_values($fields['field_country']);
    $lower_case_countries = array_map('strtolower', $countries);
    $formatted_date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time());

    $user = User::load($uid);
    $username = $user->getUsername();
    $roles = $user->getRoles();
    if (in_array('administrator', $roles) || in_array('advisor', $roles)) {
      return;
    }

    // Convert Birthdate to age and update ages (Can be done during migrations)
    // Subtract year of birth from Registration date
    // Ex: Registration Date: June 1st, 2020
    // Year of birth: 2005
    // Age: 15 (June 1st, 2020 – June 1st 2005)
    $age = $user->get('field_age')->value ?? '';
    $reg_timestamp = $user->getCreatedTime();
    $birthdate = strtotime($user->get('field_birthdate')->value) ?? '';
    if(!$age && $birthdate) {
      $reg_month = date('m', $reg_timestamp);
      $reg_day = date('d', $reg_timestamp);
      $birth_year = date('Y', $birthdate);
      $new_birthday = $birth_year.'-'.$reg_month.'-'.$reg_day;
      $birth_date_time = new DateTime($new_birthday);
      $diff = $today->diff($birth_date_time);
      $user->set('field_age', $diff->y);
    } else if ($age) {
      $reg_date = date('Y-m-d', $reg_timestamp);
      $diff = $today->diff(new DateTime($reg_date));
      $new_age = $age + $diff->y;
      $user->set('field_age', $new_age);
    }

    // Add Country of Residence to people who don't have them
    // Only if their Nationality is Emirati or they have an emirate of Residence and they don't have a country
    // get country options
    // compare country to options
    // if it is not in options make it other
    $country = $user->get('field_new_residence')->value;
    $nationality = strtolower(trim($user->get('field_nationality')->value));
    $emirate = $user->get('field_country_residence')->value ?? '';
    if (($nationality === 'uae/emirati citizen' || $emirate) && !$country) {
      $user->set('field_country', 'United Arab Emirates');
    } else if (!in_array(trim(strtolower($country)), $lower_case_countries)) {
      $user->set('field_country', 'Other');
    } else {
      $user->set('field_country', trim(ucwords($country)));
    }

    // Remove hashtags from existing registration codes entered by users
    $reg_code = $user->get('field_workshop_code')->value;
    if($reg_code) {
      $user->set('field_workshop_code', strtolower(str_replace ('#', '', $reg_code)));
    }

    // Levels tasks
    // task 1_1
    // complete me3 and match 3 careers
    $task_1_1 = $user->get('field_task_1_1')->value;
    $matched_degs = $user->get('field_matched_degrees')->getValue();
    if(!$task_1_1 && count($matched_degs) >= 3) {
      $user->set('field_task_1_1', 1);
      $user->set('field_task_1_1_date', $formatted_date);
    }

    // task 1_2
    // enroll in one course
    $task_1_2 = $user->get('field_task_1_2')->value;
    $enrolled_courses = $user->get('field_current_courses')->getValue();
    if(!$task_1_2 && count($enrolled_courses)) {
      $user->set('field_task_1_2', 1);
      $user->set('field_task_1_2_date', $formatted_date);
    }

    // task 2_1
    // complete 1 one course
    $task_2_1 = $user->get('field_task_2_1')->value;
    $completed_courses = $user->get('field_completed_courses')->getValue();
    if(!$task_1_2 && count($completed_courses)) {
      $user->set('field_task_2_1', 1);
      $user->set('field_task_2_1_date', $formatted_date);
  
    }

    // task 2_2
    // request certificate
    $task_2_2 = $user->get('field_task_2_2')->value;
    $certificates = $user->get('field_course_certificates')->getValue();
    foreach($certificates as $cert_string) {
      $decoded_data = json_decode($cert_string['value']);
      if(is_null($cert_data)) {
        continue;
      } else {
        $cert_data = reset($decoded_data);
      }
      if ($cert_data->grading->certificate->download_url) {
        $user->set('field_task_2_2', 1);
        $user->set('field_task_2_2_date', $formatted_date);
        break;
      }
    }

    // task 3_2
    // complete 3 online courses
    $task_3_2 = $user->get('field_task_3_2')->value;
    if(!$task_3_2 && count($completed_courses) >= 3) {
      $user->set('field_task_3_2', 1);
      $user->set('field_task_3_2_date', $formatted_date);
    }

    // Save User
    $user->save();
  }
```

What am I missing here that is causing the script build up so much memory as it processes items?

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to the suggested existing answer in the comments, but it still seems to gradually grow in memory usage in a similar rate as before.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($uids, 100);

foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
  $users = User::loadMultiple($chunk);
  
  foreach($users as $user) {
    // instead of using the `cleanUp` service method, we directly modify and save the user here now
  }

  Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->resetCache($chunk);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I commented out the `$user->save()` in the user for-loop and it performed well and memory didn't creep up... Is there a different storage cache I need to reset aside from 'user' when I save on the records?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280707/memory-leak-when-looping-through-nodes - the accepted answer is what you're looking for

Comment: I tried the accepted answer, but with `Drupal::entityTypeManage()->getStorage('user')->resetCache()` but I just keep getting a warning for each chunk `Illegal offset type in unset ContentEntityStorageBase.php:1117` and the memory appears to still be building...

Comment: Looks like the answer has a small bug, should be `->resetCache($chunk)`, minus the square brackets

Comment: Yup, that was it. It without warning now, but the memory usage is still creeping up...

Comment: @Clive It reset cache doesn't appear to work when saving the user... please see updated to question

Comment: I think at this point you'll have to profile the code properly - certainly the original code had a big memory-smell about it, but if fixing that doesn't stop the memory creep, you need to isolate where it's happening. I doubt anyone would be able to do that from afar (beyond guesswork)

Comment: This needs to be either a batch process or a queue. Check out Drupal's Batch API and Queue API.

Comment: Why does it "need" to be either of those? What's wrong with a simple script, something that any decent frameworks is able to handle without issues? Sounds more like Drupal needs to fix their memory issues with `user->save()` as that is clearly the issue here.

Comment: Like, I have literally never had an issue in any other framework with using a script to iterate over a large number of entities and modify/save them, until Drupal...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Queue. You can check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/queue/8.9.x for more information.

The point is each item will be processed one at a time, by timed chunks (30 seconds in my example). So the queue will process as many items it could in a 30 seconds span (or less, or more, you can adapt this in the annotation), then the process will stop and will restart next time the cron is run.

Over time, the queue will be treated. Caveat is if you absolutely need to have all users updated at once : with queue you can't tell how much time it will take - in my experience it's reliable - but eventually every user will be updated. We use it with a 5-minutes cron interval.

If you throw an `\Exception` in the `processItem()` function in the `QueueWorker`, the item will stay in the queue and will be reprocessed. Otherwise, the item will be delete from the queue.

You could use the `__construct()` method of the `QueueWorker` to use dependency injection to load services.

This is a pseudo/partial implementation :

- Create a queue (Worker) in your namespace `\Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\QueueWorker`
  This Worker will implement updating/saving user part (either in the body function or by using your user service).

```
    namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\QueueWorker;

    /**
     * Executes queue tasks.
     *
     * @QueueWorker(
     *   id = "mymodule.user.queue",
     *   title = @Translation("Deal user"),
     *   cron = {"time" = 30}
     * )
     */
    class UserUpdateWorker extends QueueWorkerBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * Update user.
   *
   * @param string $data
   *   What was injected : User ID. 
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public function processItem($data): void {
    $user = User::load($uid);
    // What you need to do. 
  }
```

- Create a queue (service) like this in your mymodule.services.yml

  ```
  mymodule.user.queue.service:
    class: Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueInterface
    factory: queue:get
    arguments: ['mymodule.user.queue'] // this is the annotation Worker ID.
  ```
- Use a (drush || cron || post_update hook) function to get the list of all users and send each ID in a the queue you created.

  ````
  $queue = \Drupal::service('mymodule.user.queue.service');

  $uids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
                  ->condition('status', '1')
                  ->execute();

  foreach($uids as $uid) {
     $queue->createItem($uid);
  }```
  ````

The queue will process items at the next cron.

Comment: That was going to be my fallback solution, but was just curious about why the memory issue was happening

Comment: My guess is user_load/saves within the same process across a number of entities.